# Best-Practices for posting a follow-on question?

Tags: discussion, style, hyperlinks, asking-questions, revisions

Are there best-practices for posting a follow-on question?

I am new to ELU.  I have searched ELU meta for this subject and have not yet found any information.

From my novice vantage, here are some considerations -- perhaps reasonable -- for posting a follow-on question:

1. Post a clarification or minor follow-on question as a comment to a particular proposed answer.
2. Open a completely new, separate question having its own thread if an answer is required -- even if the original question thread has not been answered and closed.
3. Include inline links to and from an original question thread and separate, related questions threads.

Discussion:

- Do the previous considerations make sense?
- Where should the question's original "owner" post a follow-on question if it neither is in response to somebody else's proposed answer nor requires a new, separate question thread? Should the owner edit the original question?

Comment: *Don't* edit somebody else's question to bear on what you want to know now rather then what was originally asked. That is so obviously unacceptable (whether on SE or anywhere else) that I am assuming your phrasing went awry in the last paragraph; you might want to edit.

Comment: @ TimLymington -- good catch -- see if the last paragraph makes better sense now -- it did not really ask what I had intended.  I fully agree on your point about changing the sense of someone else's original question.  In fact, I'm still uneasy about editing any previous post, since this is considered bad form in a typical discussion forum: it might make someone's response to a previous post seem incoherent or illogical, thus confusing the conversation. However, I can see that it is desirable for this site, since the intended end product is a good question followed by one or more good answers.

Comment: Johnny was last active Aug 14 '14. Can we close this question as POB and then delete it? It's been 192 in over four years, safe to say it won't be missed.

Comment: I've flagged it as POB, as @Mari-LouA proposed a month ago. Neither answer is worth saving.

Answer (score -1):

Here's one I did the other day [Look for Frank's comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171032/regarding-present-tense-and-future-tense) but you'll need to be quick as it's [on hold].

Seemed to be an acceptable method (no-one complained) but then no-one has bothered to answer your question so it's probably not important how you do it and therefore I'd say do whatever you feel like (except the part @TimLymington pointed out) until enough people tell you you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Well, I guess I ~9 hours was quick enough.  Good example.  Regarding the second discussion item in my question: unless questioning someone's comment, I'll tend to open a new, entirely separate question rather than to cloud the sense of the first question with a follow-on question.  I think I'll follow your lead and use ELL in addition to searching here on ELU before I post.

Answer (score -3):

There are no best-practices for this forum about posting follow-on questions.